# Stuck combining 3 numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula in Excel, not VBA please, forbidden to have such functions on my work machine.  My situation is I need a number from cell A, which is a result from Today(), combined with a number from cell B, which is a result from Now(), combined with a number from cell C which is a text number, to output as a single number.

Example:

```
          Cell A1  Cell A2  Cell A3
Formula:  TODAY()  NOW()    17709
Displays: 1011     1423     17709

Needed:   1011142317709
```

What I'm trying is this, which is a fail:  `=TEXT(O21,yy-mm)&""&TEXT(P21,hh,mm)&"""&VALUE(Q21)`

Comment: Well, that formatted poorly

Comment: The cells from your exemple do not match the one in the formula

Comment: Also, `TEXT(O21,yy-mm)` and `TEXT(P21,hh,mm)` are not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **do not** need leading zeroes to fill 5 digit placeholders for the value in Q21,

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"yymmhhmm")&TEXT(Q21, "0")
'possibly,
=TEXT(NOW(),"mmddhhmm")&TEXT(Q21, "0")
```

If you **do** need leading zeroes to fill 5 digit placeholders for the value in Q21,

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"yymmhhmm")&TEXT(Q21, "00000")
'possibly,
=TEXT(NOW(),"mmddhhmm")&TEXT(Q21, "00000")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=TEXT(O21,"yymm")&""&TEXT(P21,"hhmm")&""&VALUE(Q21)
```

Placed in quotes the number format and removed extra quote though not sure why you are adding null to the string.

To match the sample output OP provided the formula would be:

```
=TEXT(A1,"mmdd")&""&TEXT(B1,"hhmm")&VALUE(C1)
```

Comment: Note that according to your original formula you would get the last 2 digits of the year and month, not the month and day as your example provides.